# Managed switches need setup?

Tags: switch

I have 2 Unmanaged [switches](http://www.dlink.com/uk/en/business-solutions/switching/unmanaged-switches/rackmount/des-1024d-24-port-10-100mbps-desktop-switch) (100Mbps) and I want to replace them with one switch like [this](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/T1600G-52TS-(TL-SG2452).html), which is 1000Mbps but it is managed. The TL-SG2452 is plug & play or I will have to do a setup in order to work?

Comment: You should at least change the management password.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just plug it on the network without touching anything on the configuration it should behave just like an unmanaged switch.

This happens because the stock configuration generally allows this. If the switch have VLAN capabilities it come for example with a predefined VLAN1.

But do yourself a favor and at least learn how to connect to it and explore its features. If you like networking you'll be pleased.

Comment: In am newbie and I want to learn all the extra features.. can you suggest me site / book to learn all this stuff?

Comment: Well I never used a book... The manual that came with the product generally is pretty good. The terms are generic, so if you would like the terms start studying what a VLAN is. This is definitely one of the most welcomed features of managed switches. There a plenty of YouTube videos with content and generally Cisco have a very good material to start learning. Wikipedia is your friend for the basics.

Comment: Most managed switches are also addressable devices and will need (or need to obtain) their own address so a nice add to this answer would this as sometimes just "plugging the device in"  won't make it immediately work until it's got an IP from DHCP or if it needs to be configured. I've had Cisco switches that took up to a minute to get a IP before it would work :)

Comment: @BigChris : technically the switch does not need an IP address to start forwarding. It will behave just like an unmanaged switch (that is forward frames, learn MAC addresses and so on) fine without an IP address or any other configuration.

Answer (score 4):

The basic switching functionality will be there right away. This means normally all ports are enabled and assigned to the same default VLAN (usually 1). Further, usually there is Spanning Tree active by default.

So long story short: You can use the switch right out of the box, you however have the possibility to add and configure other features (for example VLANs, basic routing, security features, or other things) as required.